# Show enum text based on database column value in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

I have a model that maps to database table, I have an enum property in that model. I'm storing an `int` value in the table column and for managing things using enum for that (as I have small fix list).

My question is I want the text of enum for particular db column value.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; } // ItemId (Primary key)

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; } // CategoryId

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name (length: 100)

    [DisplayName("Item Code")]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; } // ItemCode (length: 15)

    [DisplayName("Unit Type")]
    public int? UnitId { get; set; } // UnitId
    public DateTime? UpdatedOnUtc { get; set; } // UpdatedOnUtc
    public DateTime? CreatedOnUtc { get; set; } // CreatedOnUtc

    [DisplayName("Is Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } // IsActive

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual ICollection<GatePass> GatePasses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MoveOrderItem> MoveOrderItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectItemPrice> ProjectItemPrices { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Enums.UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
}
```

I'm storing enum value in `UnitId` column and for display it value I want to show text of that enum/enum display attribute.

My enum is `UnitType`:

```
public enum UnitType
{
    Set = 1,
    Km = 2,
    No = 3,
    Kg = 4,
    Mtr = 5
}
```

My main purpose is to manage display in EF query because In EF list I will have `UnitId` but I want to display UnitType's unit text like kg,set,no,mtr etc..

I did this stuff often time in SQL using `case when as` but I don't know how to manage in EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change a `UnitType` property type to `string` and then read `enum` constant as below:

```
public string UnitType 
{ 
   get
   { 
     return Enum.GetName(typeof(UnitType), UnitId); 
   } 
}
```